# How to stop elements in list from changing?

Tags: python

I'm not really sure what is going on here. But the elements in my list keep changing.

`table._row_gen` is a generator instance, and it creates the rows for my table. Source is [here](http://pastebin.com/52kspbLG).

It returns a `dict`; I can also get the `dict` directly from `table._row_gen.stats`.

```
def test_append(self):
        start_stats = {'step':250,'offset':13,'inc':113,'danger':0,'input':None}
        gen = StatGenerator(start_stats)
        table = PathTable(gen)

        stats_list = []

        for i in xrange(50):
            stats_list.append(table._row_gen.stats)
            print stats_list[i]
            table._row_gen.next()

        assert stats_list[0]['step'] == 250
```

This should build a list of rows to `stats_list`.

**The `print` works fine and displays the correct output:**

```
{'danger': 0, 'input': None, 'step': 250, 'inc': 113, 'offset': 13}
{'enc': False, 'danger': 113, 'rnd': 216, 'step': 252, 'limit': 55552, 'offset': 13, 'inpu
{'enc': False, 'danger': 226, 'rnd': 163, 'step': 254, 'limit': 41984, 'offset': 13, 'inpu
{'enc': False, 'danger': 339, 'rnd': 151, 'step': 0, 'limit': 38912, 'offset': 26, 'input'
{'enc': False, 'danger': 452, 'rnd': 212, 'step': 2, 'limit': 54528, 'offset': 26, 'input'
{'enc': False, 'danger': 565, 'rnd': 64, 'step': 4, 'limit': 16640, 'offset': 26, 'input'
```

**But the list is malformed, and the `assert` fails:**

```
>           assert stats_list[0]['step'] == 250
E           assert 94 == 250

test_int_path_table.py:47: AssertionError
```

**After the loop:**

```
print stats_list[0]
{'enc': True, 'danger': 5650, 'rnd': 6, 'step': 94, 'limit': 1792, 'offset': 26, 'input':
```

94 should the last row. Yet all of the rows are reporting to be the same:

```
print stats_list[0] is stats_list[48]
True
```

I don't really understand why this is happening, and I would like the list to be correct (like the `print` output).

Comment: Is `table._row_gen.next()` supposed to create a new dict and assign it to `table._row_gen.stats`?  It appears that rather than creating a new dict `table._row_gen.next()` is mutating an existing dict.  Therefore each time you append it you are appending the same object.

Comment: table._row_gen.next() just returns a new dict. I want all of the dicts in the list. I don't understand why they are the same. The print statement shows what I want in the list.

Comment: How are you creating this "new" dict in `table._row_gen.next()`?  Are you starting with an empty dict on each call?  I think that `print` is just showing different mutations of the *same* dictionary.  Show us the code for `table._row_gen.next`.

Comment: Your `next` method is just altering the same state, not creating a new one. So all those elements in the list are the exact same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple solution is to make a copy. For this, you can do

```
def test_append(self):
        start_stats = {'step':250,'offset':13,'inc':113,'danger':0,'input':None}
        gen = StatGenerator(start_stats)
        table = PathTable(gen)

        stats_list = []

        for i in xrange(50):
            stats_list.append(table._row_gen.stats.copy()) # <=== the copy call makes a new copy and solves your problem.
            print stats_list[i]
            table._row_gen.next()

        assert stats_list[0]['step'] == 250
```

Also, the `next` call at the end of the for block is extraneous. It can be combined using

```
def test_append(self):
        start_stats = {'step':250,'offset':13,'inc':113,'danger':0,'input':None}
        gen = StatGenerator(start_stats)
        table = PathTable(gen)

        stats_list = []

        for i in xrange(50):
            stats_list.append(next(table._row_gen).copy())
            print stats_list[i]

        assert stats_list[0]['step'] == 250
```

If you're in control of the pastebin code, the stats property should return a defensive copy.

```
    @property
    def stats(self):
            return self._stats.copy()
```

and the `next` method should return a defensive copy too.

```
    def next(self):
            ''' Generates and returns stats. '''
            row = self._stats
            row['step'] = self._genStepId(self._stats['step'])
            row['offset'] = self._genOffset(self._stats['offset'], self._stats['step'])
            row['danger'] = self._genDanger(self._stats['danger'], self.stats['inc'])
            row['rnd'] = self._genRnd(self.rnlut[self._stats['step']], self._stats['offset'])
            row['limit'] = self._genDangerLimit(self._stats['rnd'])
            row['enc'] = self._genEnc(self._stats['danger'], self._stats['limit'])

            return self.stats
```

If you do the above two blocks, the copy in the first two is no longer necessary.